# Monad for an API response

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I want to build an ApiClient that transforms API responses into a Monad.

Normally a successful response looks like this:

```
{
  ok: true,
  data: { ... },
  headers,
}
```

And the error response like this:

```
{
  ok: false,
  error: { ... },
  headers,
}
```

My first approach was using the **Either** monad so I no longer need the **ok** field. The **Left** value would be *error* and the **Right** one *data*. But what should I do with *headers* and other meta information of the response?

Most of the time I do not care that much about the meta information of an api response. I like how the **Either** monad helps to focus my code in the most important value. However now I must hack my *data* and *error* fields.

Is there another monad suitable for these cases? Or is this problem solved by some other approach?

Comment: It seems to me as if you want to replace a nested product type (record) with a sum type (or rather a sum of products). You can use `Either` as the starting point and extend each data constructor (for success and error respectively) by the corresponding properties. If the `error` property is always of the same type, you don't need a parameterized type for the error case. So instead of `Response e a` for instance you can just define `Response a`, where `a` is the polymorphic type for the value of the `data` property.

Comment: Are you intending to implement the `bind` and `return` functions for this monad yourself? In this case, you have lots of options, but the `Either` approach is definitely the right starting place as mentioned by @ftor. Since this is javascript, your `bind` could accept a function of type `(a, headers) -> M b` and you could still pass a function of type `a -> M b` if you weren't interested in the headers for this particular operation. I can expand on what I mean in an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use it later. you have an either with the two extra fields on it. I would recommend replacing the properties ok, data and error with an either or a result type and keeping the headers and meta in the object